# SQL query - double condition on relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get all users that speak English **and** French based on the schema above. How can I achieve this?

I've tried with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM User
INNER JOIN UserLanguage on User.idUser = UserLanguage.idUser
INNER JOIN Language on UserLanguage.idLanguage = Language.idLanguage
WHERE Language.name = "FR" AND Language.name = "EN"
```

[image: SQL Schema]

Comment: i think your query is right as per your requirement .. what is the problem ??

Comment: @Dhaval - the reason why the query is wrong is that the WHERE clause is impossible:  The name can't be both FR and EN - for the same record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a subquery that counts the number of languages (that are either FR or EN) spoken by each user. It then returns all the id of all users that speaks both of these languages. The outer query returns all columns for each of these users:

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
WHERE idUser IN (
  SELECT UserLanguage.idUser
  FROM
    UserLanguage INNER JOIN Language
    ON UserLanguage.idLanguage = Language.idLanguage
  WHERE
    Language.name IN ("FR", "EN")
  GROUP BY
    UserLanguage.idUser
  HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT Language.name)=2
)
```

Comment: You can't use `SELECT *` cause you will get ambiguous fields error.

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев i changed it to Users.* because it's better, but I'm selecting only from Users so there are no problems about ambiguous fields error

Answer (score 2):

Change your conditional from

```
WHERE Language.name = "FR" AND Language.name = "EN"
```

to

```
WHERE (Language.name = "FR" OR Language.name = "EN")
```

You should never have an entry in the database that has two values for a single field, but if you use the "OR" operator, you should be selecting the entry if either value is equal.

Comment: OP wants those people who speaks both english and french .. not any one of them

Comment: @Emilie do you need to return all people that speaks either english or french (like this answer), or do you need to return all people that speaks both?

Comment: @Emilie - doesn't this return users who speak at least one of the languages (this doesn't guarantee they speak both)

Comment: @Dhaval I got lucky I guess :P  I edited the question to reflect the answer I provided.

Comment: @dckuehn i don't know if it is correct to edit the question to reflect the answer...

Comment: @fthiella , do you think I should undo it?  This seems like a good topic for meta.  I was just thinking of anyone coming across this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM User
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM UserLanguage 
            INNER JOIN Language
              ON UserLanguage.idLanguage = Language.idLanguage
                 AND (Language.name = 'FR' OR Language.name = 'EN')
            WHERE User.idUser = UserLanguage.idUser)
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to look at a join from the perspective of what the 'centre' of the circle is. In this case you are trying to join 'User' to 'Language' via UserLanguage, so your FROM table needs to be 'UserLanguage'.

So basically you're looking at:

```
SELECT * FROM UserLanguage
INNER JOIN User ON Userlanguage.idUser = User.idUser
INNER JOIN Language on Userlanguage.idLanguage = Language.idLanguage
WHERE (Language.Name = 'EN' OR Language.Name = 'FR');
```

Comment: so what will be the difference .. this is inner join so order will not make any difference..

Comment: your WHERE clause is impossible to be true:  the language name can't be both FR AND EN

Comment: well spotted! Given the fact I told my colleague not an hour ago that his query was faulty because of a similar reason the joke's on me now! DOH!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM User
    INNER JOIN UserLanguage on User.idUser = UserLanguage.idUser
    INNER JOIN Language on UserLanguage.idLanguage = Language.idLanguage
 WHERE Language.name = "FR" AND Language.name = "EN"
```

You just need to change the

```
 WHERE Language.name = "FR" AND Language.name = "EN"
```

to

```
 WHERE (Language.name = "FR" OR Language.name = "EN")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Users u INNER JOIN UserLanguage ul
ON u.idUser = ul.idUser JOIN Language l
ON ul.idLanguage = l.idLanguage
WHERE l.LanguageName IN ('EN', 'FR')
ORDER BY u.idUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the UserLanguage table to itself, e.g:

```
SELECT T1.idUser 
FROM UserLanguage AS T1
INNER JOIN UserLanguage AS T2
ON T1.idUser=T2.idUser
WHERE T1.idLanguage='EN'
AND T2.idLanguage='FR'
```

Comment: fyi:  the language name has to be either EN or FR, not the idLanguage